# How to add values to the list in C#

Tags: c#, ado.net, livecharts

I was trying to add values to the list, but I keep getting the error "ArgumentOutOfRangeException", I'm using a livecharts (chart library).

here's my code:

```
string constring = "server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
        string Query = "SELECT Therapist, COUNT(*) AS magnitude FROM dbinfo.tblorder GROUP BY Therapist ORDER BY magnitude DESC";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDB = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;


        try
        {
            con.Open();
            myReader = cmdDB.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                int valuez = myReader.GetInt16("magnitude");
                cartesianChart1.Series[1].Values.Add(valuez);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        Data.con.Close();
        cartesianChart1.Series = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new ColumnSeries
            {

                Title = "Therapist",
                Values =  new ChartValues<int> { 10, 50, 39, 50 }
            }
        };
         cartesianChart1.AxisX.Add(new Axis
        {
            Title = "Therapists",
            Labels = new[] { "Maria", "Susan", "Charles", "Frida" }
        });
```

Comment: I would recommend using a lightweight ORM such as [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

Comment: What line throw the Exception? What value is "out of range"?

Comment: sorry, it was from this "cartesianChart1.Series[1].Values.Add(valuez);"

Answer (score 2):

You should be initializing certesianChart.Series before you read data from the data reader

Also the change the index to zero

```
cartesianChart1.Series[0].Values.Add(valuez);
```

Here is the working code.

```
cartesianChart1.Series = new SeriesCollection
{
   new ColumnSeries
   {
       Title = "Therapist",
       Values =  new ChartValues<int> { 10, 50, 39, 50 }
   }
};

try
{
   con.Open();
   myReader = cmdDB.ExecuteReader();

   while (myReader.Read())
   {
      int valuez = myReader.GetInt16("magnitude");
      cartesianChart1.Series[0].Values.Add(valuez);
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cartesianChart1.Series only contains 1 item as defined here:

```cs
    cartesianChart1.Series = new SeriesCollection
    {
        new ColumnSeries
        {

            Title = "Therapist",
            Values =  new ChartValues<int> { 10, 50, 39, 50 }
        }
    };
```

You try to access the 2nd item in this part:

```cs
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            int valuez = myReader.GetInt16("magnitude");
            cartesianChart1.Series[1].Values.Add(valuez);
        }
```

Try to access the 1st item:

```cs
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            int valuez = myReader.GetInt16("magnitude");
            cartesianChart1.Series[0].Values.Add(valuez);
        }
```